# Add cron job using php

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to add cron job using the following code. But the problem is neither i am getting appropriate result nor any error. When i check crons using putty there is no cron added.
php_ssh2 extension is required to make connection.

```
<?php

Class Test {
// Constructor to make connection
function __construct($host=NULL, $port=NULL, $username=NULL, $password=NULL) {

  $path_length     = strrpos(__FILE__, "/");    
  $this->path      = substr(__FILE__, 0, $path_length) . '/';    
  $this->handle    = 'crontab.txt';    
  $this->cron_file = "{$this->path}{$this->handle}";     

try
{
    if (is_null($host) || is_null($port) || is_null($username) || is_null($password)) throw new Exception("Please specify the host, port, username and password!");

    if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect"))
        die('Function ssh2_connect not found, you cannot use ssh2 here');

    $this->connection = @ssh2_connect($host, $port);

   //var_dump($this->connection); die('heref');
    if ( ! $this->connection) throw new Exception("The SSH2 connection could not be established.");

    $authentication = @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password);
    if ( ! $authentication) throw new Exception("Could not authenticate '{$username}' using password: '{$password}'.");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
}
// To check if the crontab.txt file exists
private function crontab_file_exists() {
    return file_exists($this->cron_file);
}

public function remove_file() {
    if ($this->crontab_file_exists()) $this->exec("rm {$this->cron_file}");
    return $this;
}

public function append_cronjob($cron_jobs=NULL) {
    if (is_null($cron_jobs)) {
    echo "Nothing to append!  Please specify a cron job or an array of cron jobs.";
    die;
    }
      //echo $this->cron_file; die;
    $append_cronfile = "echo '";
    $append_cronfile .= (is_array($cron_jobs)) ? implode("\n", $cron_jobs) : $cron_jobs;
    $append_cronfile .= "'  >> {$this->cron_file}";
    $install_cron = "crontab{$this->cron_file}";

    $this->write_to_file()->exec($append_cronfile, $install_cron);

    return $this;
 }

public function write_to_file($path=NULL, $handle=NULL){
   if ( ! $this->crontab_file_exists())
   {
    $this->handle = (is_null($handle)) ? $this->handle : $handle;
    $this->path   = (is_null($path))   ? $this->path   : $path;

    $this->cron_file = "{$this->path}{$this->handle}";

  echo  $init_cron = "crontab -l > {$this->cron_file} && [ -f {$this->cron_file} ] || > {$this->cron_file}";
  die;

    $this->exec($init_cron);
}

return $this;
  }

public function exec() {
    $argument_count = func_num_args();

    try
    {
    if ( ! $argument_count) throw new Exception("There is nothing to execute, no arguments specified.");

    $arguments = func_get_args();

    $command_string = ($argument_count > 1) ? implode(" && ", $arguments) : $arguments[0];
    $stream = @ssh2_exec($this->connection, $command_string);

    if ( ! $stream) throw new Exception("Unable to execute the specified commands: <br />{$command_string}");

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}

return $this;
}

   }

$Runobj = new Test('12.0.8.158', 22, 'test', 'mind@123');
$response = $Runobj->append_cronjob('* * * * * command >/dev/null');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($response);

  ?>
```

This was actually a tutorial which i picked. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Its the same code i have used. But no results.
No success and no errors